# How to Convert raster in tiff file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I have the Matlab code for hdf5 image as given below which convert the hdf image into the output image (temperature K) in png format as shown. Can anyone guide me how to modify the code so that the final image should be in tiff format which can be used in ArcGis. 
I have several images of temperature and rainfall in hdf5 format and i want to learn how to convert them into Geotiff for further processing in ArcGIS software. My next question is that why it is showing a full globe and colourful irregular pattern of temperature data as shown in output Image. It should be in WGS1984 system. 
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9i4I.png)

```
% Copyright (C) 2016-2018 The HDF Group
%   All Rights Reserved 
%
%  This example code illustrates how to access and visualize GPM L1C file
% in MATLAB. 
%
%  If you have any questions, suggestions, comments on this example, please 
% use the HDF-EOS Forum (http://hdfeos.org/forums). 
% 
%  If you would like to see an  example of any other NASA HDF/HDF-EOS data 
% product that is not listed in the HDF-EOS Comprehensive Examples page 
% (http://hdfeos.org/zoo), feel free to contact us at eoshelp@hdfgroup.org 
% or post it at the HDF-EOS Forum (http://hdfeos.org/forums).
%                                   
% Usage:save this script and run (without .m at the end)
%                                   
%
% $matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r GPM_1CF19SSMIS_05
%
% Tested under: MATLAB R2017a
% Last updated: 2018-1-22

clear

% Open the HDF5 File.
FILE_NAME = '1C.F19.SSMIS.XCAL2016-V.20150906-S011918-E030110.007356.V05A.hdf5';
file_id = H5F.open(FILE_NAME, 'H5F_ACC_RDONLY', 'H5P_DEFAULT');
h5disp(FILE_NAME)
% Open the dataset.
DATAFIELD_NAME = 'S1/Tc';
data_id = H5D.open(file_id, DATAFIELD_NAME);
;

Lat_NAME='S1/Latitude';
lat_id=H5D.open(file_id, Lat_NAME);

Lon_NAME='S1/Longitude';
lon_id=H5D.open(file_id, Lon_NAME);

% Read the dataset.
data=H5D.read(data_id,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT');

lat=H5D.read(lat_id,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT');

lon=H5D.read(lon_id,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT');


% Read the units.
ATTRIBUTE = 'units';
attr_id = H5A.open_name (data_id, ATTRIBUTE);
units = H5A.read(attr_id, 'H5ML_DEFAULT');

% Read title attribute.
ATTRIBUTE = 'LongName';
attr_id = H5A.open_name (data_id, ATTRIBUTE);
long_name=H5A.read (attr_id, 'H5ML_DEFAULT');

% Read the fill value attribute.
ATTRIBUTE = '_FillValue';
attr_id = H5A.open_name (data_id, ATTRIBUTE);
fillvalue = H5A.read(attr_id, 'H5ML_DEFAULT');


% Close and release resources.
H5A.close (attr_id)
H5D.close (data_id);
H5F.close (file_id);

% Subset data.
data = data(1,:,:);

% Replace the fill value with NaN.
data(data==fillvalue) = NaN;
dset_name = sprintf('%s', long_name);
disp_name = strcat(dset_name, ' (nchannel1=0)')

f = figure('Name', FILE_NAME, ...
           'Renderer', 'zbuffer', ...
           'Position', [0,0,800,600], ...
           'visible', 'off');

% Create the plot.
axesm('MapProjection','eqdcylin',...
      'Frame','on','Grid','on', ...
      'MeridianLabel','on','ParallelLabel','on','MLabelParallel', ...
      'south')

% Plot the data.
cm = colormap('Jet');
min_data=min(min(data));
max_data=max(max(data));
caxis([min_data max_data]);
k = size(data);
[count, n] = size(cm);
lat = lat(:)';
lon = lon(:)';
data = data(:)';
scatterm(lat, lon, 1, data);
coast = load('coast.mat');
plotm(coast.lat,coast.long,'k')

tightmap;

h = colorbar();

% An HDF5 string attribute is an array of characters.
% Without the following conversion, the characters in unit will appear 
% in a vertical direction.
units1 = sprintf('%s', char(units));

% long_name is pretty long so use a small font.
set (get(h, 'title'), 'string', units1, 'FontSize', 8, ...
                   'Interpreter', 'None', ...
                   'FontWeight','bold');

% Unit is also long so we use a small font.
title({FILE_NAME; disp_name}, ... 
      'Interpreter', 'None', 'FontSize', 10,'FontWeight','bold');
saveas(f, [FILE_NAME '.m.png']);
exit;
```

Comment: Try: `saveas(f, [FILE_NAME '.m.tif']);`

Comment: will it be with coordinates lat lon to be used in gis erdas and envi softwares

Comment: No, `saveas` just saves the figure as an image. You can convert the figure to image (RGB matrix): `I = frame2im(getframe(f));`, and save `I` using `geotiffwrite`. I don't know if displaying the image, and getting the displayed frame as an image is the right way to go.